# MVVM - Share/Reuse ViewModels between Silverlight and WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, share, reusability

Is it possible to share viewmodels across platforms - WPF/Silverlight? I started down the path of putting my VMs in a separate assembly and soon came to ICommand - which then led me to ask this question? Is this possible, and if so is it good to do so? We have a possibility in the future of having a client application for WPF and Silverlight, so I would like to not have to duplicate VMs for both.

Answer (score 4):

You can potentially do this using the [Portable Library Tools CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/01/19/announcing-portable-library-tools-ctp-justin-van-patten.aspx).  This allows you to target the full framework as well as Silverlight in a single library project.

Otherwise, it is possible, sort of.  You still need two separate projects (for practical purposes), but can typically use a single source file.  Have each project using the same source files keeps the reuse in place - but does require manual synchronization of the files.  You can also add platform-specific functionality easily in this case via partial classes or defines, which does help to keep some of the workarounds for missing Silverlight functionality easy to maintain.

Comment: I think the Portable Library option will be your best bet, but it will force you to code to the lowest common denominator.  Really, for ViewModels this shouldn't be a problem as you should abstract any View related idiosyncrasies to the View and any platform idiosyncrasies to a service layer.

Answer (score 0):

[Almost] whatever is possible in Silverlight, is possible in WPF, too. So if you have a VM working in Silverlight, it will [mostly] work with WPF.

From the other point of view, WPF offers richer possibilities, so you might want to use them in your WPF part of code. You can use the usual `#ifdef Silverlight`-like tricks.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080348/targeting-both-net-3-5-and-silverlight) might be useful.